# Como retornar o timestamp do timezone definido?

Tags: php, datetime

Estou tentando retornar o **timestamp** da minha cidade.

Quando eu uso a instrução ***('Y-m-d H:i:s')*** ele retorna a hora certa da minha região mas eu preciso retornar o ***timestamp*** dessa hora e parece que com a instrução ***('U')*** eu só consigo a hora do servidor e não o ***timestamp*** da hora da minha região.

```
function agora (){
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Campo_Grande");
    $dftz011 = date_default_timezone_get();
    $dtms011 = new DateTime();
    return $dtms011->format('U'); 
}
```

Estou usando [***esta ferramenta***](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) para converter o timestamp retornado e quando faço a conversão sempre me retornar a hora do servidor e não do timezone da minha região.

Como retornar o timestamp da minha região?

Comment: Mesmo `echo $dtms011->format('H:i:s');` não retorna a hora certa?

Comment: Este retorna a hora certa. Com **('U')** não retorna.

Comment: vc quer um timestamp com o timezone isso?

Comment: Exatamente @rray

Comment: Qual é a finalidade, achei interessante.

Comment: Os nomes das variáveis estão engraçados

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para pegar o timestamp convertido com o timezone, some timestamp com o offset(diferença em realação ao greenwitch em segundos). Use os métodos
[getTimestamp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) e [getOffset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getoffset.php) da classe DateTime.

```
<?php
$data = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
echo 'TimeStamp: '. ($data->getTimestamp() + $data->getOffset());
```

Saída: 1444269422, corresponde a: Thu, 08 Oct 2015 01:57:02 GMT

[Exemplo - 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/gb9LO)

[Exemplo com mensagem engraçada - ideone](https://ideone.com/u1l22J)

**Referências**

[epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php)

[How to get Unix timestamp in php based on timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8668108/1342547)

[Adjusting Timestamps for Time Zones](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/a/Adjusting-Timestamps-For-Time-Zones.htm)